# NodeJS -> Error: write after end (only after first request)

Tags: node.js, http, express, httprequest, httpresponse

In my express app i have the route below:

```
router.get('/generatedData', function (req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Connection'          , 'Transfer-Encoding');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type'        , 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding'   , 'chunked');

    var Client = someModule.client;  
    var client = Client();

    client.on('start', function() {  
        console.log('start');
    });

    client.on('data', function(str) {
        console.log('data');
        res.write(str);
    });

    client.on('end', function(msg) { 
        client.stop();
        res.end();
    });

    client.on('err', function(err) { 
        client.stop();
        res.end(err);
    });

    client.on('end', function() {  
          console.log('end');
    });

    client.start();


});
```

On first call everything works fine (console)

```
We've got ourselves a convoy on port 3000
start
data
data
data
data
data
...
data
end
GET /generatedData 200 208.426 ms - -
```

I get all the data and `res.end()` is being called and successfully closes the request.

The problem starts after first request. I make the exact same request (new one of course) and i get the following error (console):

```
start
data
data
data
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write after end
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:439:15)
at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/projects/xxxx/routes/index.js:33:17)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/projects/xxxx/lib/someModule.js:116:32)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1412:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This happens without `res.end()` being called.
I manage to get some data before the crash.

How can i get this error without `res.end()` being called at all?

Do i somehow save the previous `res` instance?

Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: can you do a console.log one line before each res.end() in your code?

Comment: sure. on the first request it works fine `start\ndata\ndata\ndata\n...\nend`
and on further requests it crashes before reaching any  `res.end()` as i described above `start\ndata\ndata\ndata\nevents.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event...`

Comment: What is the `someModule.client`? Can you provide the module name?

Comment: It's a module i built. It works fine emitting `end` only once, no problem there. Is there something else to check in `someModule.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. My module was extened by EventEmitter and each time i catch event in router - it stays there, end on second call there are two eventlisteners not one. Setting "once" instead of "on" - worked for me.

```
client.once('start', function() {  
        console.log('start');
});
```

instead of

```
client.on('start', function() {  
        console.log('start');
});
```